# Storing JSON in Mysql table Using akka http

Tags: mysql, json, akka-http

I am working On creating the rest interface from Akka-Http, and Storing the POST information in the MySql table using Slick.

```
CREATE TABLE  source (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
type VARCHAR(100),
source_json BLOB,
create_date VARCHAR(10),
modify_date VARCHAR(10),
created_by VARCHAR(100),
modified_by VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Json

```
{  
"id":"101",
"type":"prototype1",
"description":"pull",
"source_json":[  
  {  
     "v1":"neo",
     "v2":"leo"
  }
],
"create_date":"12/12/12",
"modify_date":"",
"created_by":"User",
"modified_by":"user"
}
```

Akka-HTTP 
routes

```
 val route = (path("CreateSource") & post){
  entity(as [SourceEntity]){sourceEntity :SourceEntity =>
    complete(createDataSource(sourceEntity).map(_.asJson))
  }
```

Case class

```
case class SourceEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, `type`: String,  description: String,source_json: String,create_date:String,modify_date:String,created_by:String,modified_by:String){
```

require(!dataSourceName.isEmpty, "dataSourceName.empty")
}

I need to store source_json value into the table for which I am getting

```
The request content was malformed:
```

when I  do the POST Call

Is it due to the Akka Http Unmarshalling ?

Comment: Looks like you only want to partially decode the json to the case class. Is that correct ? you want to store a `source_json` as a blob in your database table. Im not sure what json library your using for the marshalling so I cant help further. Maybe try having `source_json: Json` or something in your case class. or `source_json: Seq[Map[String,String]]` then json encode it again when saving to the DB, but thats not great. Its better to validate what you save, and enforce the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SourceEntity` case class specifies `source_json : String` but the actual json defines it as an array of Strings:

> "source_json":[
>     {
>        "v1":"neo",
>        "v2":"leo"
>     } 
>   ]

You can just change the case class definition:

```
case class SourceEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, 
                        `type`: String,  
                        description: String,
                        source_json: Array[String],
                        ...)
```

Comment: I need to store it in the MySQL table, I did try with Blob 
case class SourceEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, 
                        `type`: String,  
                        description: String,
                        source_json: java.sql.Blob,
                        ...)
but then it gives error

--->      Error:(22, 17) could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[com.akka.SourceEntity]
      entity(as [SourceEntity]){sourceEntity :SourceEntity =>

Comment: @Freeman Then change the structure of the json specification.  I'm simply noting that your case class definition doesn't match the json.  There's not getting around that part...